# I need to programmatically set the date the OS returns to Java

Tags: date, jvm

I need to set the date that JVM would normally get from the OS.

Why? We have an app that interacts with a legacy app. All data on the legacy is always some date in the past (the client does reporting on a saved copy of live data (yesterday's data ) so as not to affect the response time of transactions on the live machine and demo's are done on dev machines, also some date in the past)

Our app needs to post transactions no later than the date on the legacy app. The legacy app lives on a different server. We have a process that returns the current date of the data and need to get the Java app to work entirely on that date.

We can't change the system date since a datawarehouse also runs on that box. So the only alternative is to change the date that JVM thinks it's getting from the OS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Own java agent should do the trick:

http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-1

I suppose that intercepting System.currentTimeMillis() calls should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for that... we're off to 1) understand it and 2) try it.. will get back to you!